# Layout PySimpleGUI IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

im using GUI in a client using PySimpleGUI and im trying to to understand why im getting an IndexError: list index out of range the second time it activates

from my understanding the text im trying to show is too long for the computer to handle but i dont know how to fix it.

```
def main():
    server_msg = ""

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        server_address = (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
        sock.connect(server_address)

        while server_msg != '8|':
            sock.sendall(get_client_msg().encode())
            server_msg = sock.recv(1024).decode()
            if server_msg.split("|")[0] != '8':
                layout = [[sg.Text(server_msg.split("|")[1])],
                          [sg.Button('Ok')]]
                window = sg.Window('Pink Floyd', layout)
                event, values = window.read()

                window.close()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you split text then you should check what you get. maybe there was no `"|"` and you get list with only one element - and you can't use `[1]` to get second element. Or simply you should first check `print( server_msg )` to see what you get. Socket is primitive object and it doesn't have to `recv` all data at once - there can be delay on internet - it may need to run `recv` few time to get all. OR you should first send message size (always as string with the same size - ie. 4) and late first get 4 bytes to get message size, and later run `recv` until you get all message.